# ios, UI behavior, buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am new to ios, coming from heavy UI work in C#. 
I have an app that I wanna control which button are enabled disabled based on some logic in my code.
to do this I created a small method to handle the state of the buttons, like so :

```
-(void)activateUI:(BOOL *)activate {

    [ validateDataBtn setEnabled: *activate ] ;
    [ modifyCompDataBtn setEnabled: *activate ] ;
    [ saveCompDataBtn setEnabled: *activate ] ;
}
```

Where all of those IBOutlets are bound to UI buttons like so :

```
__weak IBOutlet UIButton *saveCompDataBtn;
__weak IBOutlet UIButton *modifyCompDataBtn;
__weak IBOutlet UIButton *validateDataBtn;
```

when I run the app I get an exception on the first line of my method :

```
[ validateDataBtn setEnabled: *activate ] ;
```

the error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address =0X0)
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: My, my. I just realized how badly I messed this one up.

Incorrect: <s>First off, you shouldn't be using `BOOL *`, and if you ever did use `BOOL *` you would reference it as `&activate`, not `*activate`. The `*` in C/Objective-C means the variable is a pointer; it contains an address to a block of memory. `&` dereferences pointers to access the value on the other side.</s>

Correct: An `*` indicates that the argument is a pointer, and is also used to deference a pointer. An `&` in front of a variable indicates that you want to use the address of the variable in memory. I mixed them up. This means your original code is correct; the problem is that you probably call it using `[self activateUI:someBOOL]`, which passes a BOOL, then tries to deference it like a pointer due to the `*`.

You might be getting confused since objects are passed as `<object type> *` because all variables used to handle instances of objects are pointers. BOOL, however, is `typedef`ed to `int`, which is primitive, thus the `*` is not needed. Your method should be:

```
- (void) activateUI:(BOOL)activate {
    [validateDataBtn setEnabled: activate];
    [modifyCompDataBtn setEnabled: activate];
    [saveCompDataBtn setEnabled: activate];
}

//called like this: [self activateUI: someBOOL];
```

If you really DID mean to pass a pointer to a `BOOL` as an argument use what you originally wrote, but you need to call it like this:

```
[self activateUI: &someBOOL];
```

If you declare the method to take a pointer to a `BOOL` (`BOOL *`), and dereference it inside the method body (`*someBOOL`), you need to pass the address to the `BOOL` (`&someBOOL`), not the `BOOL` itself. If you declare the method to take a `BOOL` itself (just `BOOL`), and use it directly in the method body (`someBOOL`), you need to pass the `BOOL` itself (`someBOOL`).

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
- (void)activateUI:(BOOL)activate {
    [validateDataButton setEnabled:activate];
    // etc...
}
```

I'm not sure why you need to use a pointer to the `BOOL` activate...

EDIT:

As an illustration of scalar vs. pointer access:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface Foo:NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTextField *field;
- (void)activateUI:(BOOL *)activate;
- (void)activateUIScalar:(BOOL)activate;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize field;

- (void)activateUI:(BOOL *)activate {
    NSLog(@"%s - setting to: %d",__FUNCTION__,*activate);
    [[self field] setEnabled:*activate];
}

- (void)activateUIScalar:(BOOL)activate {
    NSLog(@"%s - setting to %d (scalar)",__FUNCTION__, activate);
    [[self field] setEnabled:activate];
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    BOOL flag = NO;
    Foo *myFoo = [Foo new];
    [myFoo activateUI:&flag];

    flag = YES;
    [myFoo activateUI:&flag];

    //  now using scalar (99.999% of the time the right way)
    [myFoo activateUIScalar:YES];
    [myFoo activateUIScalar:NO];

    [myFoo release];
    [p release];
}
```

prints the following to the console:

```
2012-10-20 14:49:14.228 Untitled 4[27444:707] -[Foo activateUI:] - setting to: 0
2012-10-20 14:49:14.230 Untitled 4[27444:707] -[Foo activateUI:] - setting to: 1
2012-10-20 14:49:14.230 Untitled 4[27444:707] -[Foo activateUIScalar:] - setting to 1 (scalar)
2012-10-20 14:49:14.231 Untitled 4[27444:707] -[Foo activateUIScalar:] - setting to 0 (scalar)
```